# Capitalize a substring within a string

Tags: python, string, python-2.x

I'm trying to create something like:

```
string: How do you do today?
substring: o

>>> hOw dO yOu dO tOday?
```

I've already written the rest of the code (prompting for strings etc.), I am just stuck on having to capitalize the substring within the string.

Comment: See `help(str.replace)`, `help(str.upper)`.

Comment: what about multiple 'o' inside, or only the 2nd 'o' have to change ?

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> s='How do you do today?'
>>> sub_s='o'
>>> s.replace(sub_s, sub_s.upper())
'HOw dO yOu dO tOday?'
```

And can get more complicated if you only want to change some (i.e., the 2nd one), one liner:

```
>>> ''.join([item.upper() if i==[idx for idx, w in enumerate(s) if w==sub_s][1] else item for i, item in enumerate(s)])
'How dO you do today?'
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `upper` instead of `capitalize`?

Comment: Yes, I should :), always confuses non-English speakers.

Comment: What happen if the string has multiple 'o'

Comment: @yopy, you mean the `substring` has multiple `'o'`? BTW, if you only need to change some `substings`, see edit.