# How can I capitalize a substring in a string in Python?

Tags: python

```
string = raw_input("Please enter a string:")
string = string.lower()
print string
substring = raw_input("Please enter a substring:")
```

That's where I am in the code so far, I have to capitalize the substring that the user has put in but I have no clue how.

Comment: As in [`string = abcde` and `substring = bc`, and the result being aBCde](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21152525)?

Comment: How do you define your substring? All you are doing here is converting whatever the user entered into lowercase.

Comment: Yes @Tshepang, that is what I am attempting for!

Comment: @BurhanKhalid That's the beginning of my code. The next step is capitalizing the substring within the string in which I do not know how to do.

Comment: What do you mean "the substring"? You mean each _word_?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid no, I'm prompting the user to enter a substring which could be simply a letter, a couple of letters together or a word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `replace` method of the string.

```
string = raw_input("Please enter a string: ").lower()
substring = raw_input("Please enter a substring: ").lower()
print string.replace(substring, substring.upper())
```

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU! OMG IT WORKS HALLELUJAH

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
substring = raw_input("Please enter a substring:")
substring = substring.upper()
print substring
```

Comment: I attempted this and it just capitalizes the substring by itself rather than the substring within the string! thanks for the attempt though!

Comment: Ahhh... okay, your instructions are not clear at all.  Elaborate on what you need exactly in your question.  Show an example etc...

Answer (score 0):

Idea: Find substring in string (in real cases, add some error checking), and construct new string based on this information:

```
string = "the quick brown fox..."
print string
substring = "uic"
start = string.find(substring)
new_string = string[:start] + substring.upper() + string[start + len(substring):]
print new_string
```